# The facebook dialog api not working

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

i develop an ios app and use the facebook dialog api, it worked fine over a month.
How ever it suddenly not work now
The reference facebook document from
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/
and i Tried the sampele link. the same error message appeared 
http://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/&display=touch
Any one knows what happened.....
it shows "There was a problem generating the Feed story from the provided data."

---

it works today. 
I think this problem was facebook server side error.
i didn't change any thing and it works today.

Comment: Yup. It seems is broken. All requests I've tried within my apps does not work anymore.

Comment: This was a bug yesterday which has since been resolved - you should check the live status and bug tracker on Facebook's developer site if you think there's an issue

Answer (score 0):

Same here, with that request (I removed good params but the error is here) :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Ffeed%3Flink%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ffr.xxx.com%252F%26description%3Dxxx%26caption%3Dxxx%26picture%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ffr.xxx.com%252Fimgs%252FlampeWho.png%26name%3Dxxx%26app_id%3Dxxx%26redirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26sdk%3D2%26display%3Dtouch